# Can you force the "move-by-word" keyboard shortcut to count \, $ and braces as part of the word?

Tags: mac, texshop, keyboard

I'm using OS 10.6, and I like to use the option-arrow command to move forwards and backward one word at a time. But one thing is annoying to me:

If the cursor is here:

> ```
>   \command
>           ^
> ```

option-leftarrrow moves it here:

> ```
>  \command
>   ^
> ```

when I really want it here:

> ```
>  \command    
>  ^
> ```

And similarly with other special characters like $, braces etc.

One reason this is a pain is because I'd like to be able to select a whole command using the shortcut shift-option-arrow. It's also annoying because it really slows down navigation through a long equation.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Hopefully it would be an OS X  or TexShop preference, since I use TexShop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using Command + Arrow keys is a solution for you, it jump's to before the 1st character in the line, although this won't work decently if you use tabs / spaces for indention

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip, however I'm interested in moving the cursor single word at a time